# Android Java calling if AND else block of code

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am using ORMLite, and have created a custom DAO that extends from the ORMLite dao framework. In the custom dao, I override the create method, and add some logic. I query for a list of entities, create a new one if it doesn't exist, and return the id of the existing one if it does. The query is working fine, as I'm debugging and checking the list object at runtime. However, anytime that the list size is 0, it executes the first block of the if..else, and then the second block, completely ignoring the return statement. If the list is not empty, it works as expected.

Anyone know why this would be acting funky? I even changed the override method name to 'persist' in case it was was recursively calling itself for some reason, and it didn't work.

```
@Override
public int create(DigitalAsset dAsset) throws SQLException {
        List<DigitalAsset> assets = this.queryForMatching(dAsset);

        if (assets.size() == 0) {
            return super.create(dAsset);
        }
        else {
            return assets.get(0).getId();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `super.create` doesn't just return the same ID? Have you tried putting log statements in each `if/else` block? To be honest, there is absolutely no reason this would happen. Not only should the `else` only execute if not empty, but `return` should end the method.

Comment: Hmmmm... Are you sure it's returning `assets.get(0).getId()`? Wouldn't it be erroring out if it were going to the else? Sometimes the debugger goes to a different return statement, because of the way the byte code was generated. You can try changing your logic, to not have returns e.g. `int id = -1; if (0) {  id = super... } else { id = assets...} return id; }`

Comment: I have also tried setting an int and then return that instead. I know it is running through both blocks because I have debugged the code and stepped through. And that is what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty dumb right now, but upon further research, I found that the ORMLite create method returns the number of affected rows, not the id. It turns out the code wasn't running through both blocks at all. It was late and I probably wasn't fully aware at the time.